# How to write universal generic type handling nullable values and references?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

```
    public sealed class MyClass<T>
    {
        private T? myField;
    }
```

This code compiles fine, yet when I use it with reference type (like T=string) I will get nullable `myField` (as expected). But when I use value type (like `int`) I will get **non-nullable** `myField` which I didn't expect, especially considering lack of error.

Is it possible to write universal type holding nullable value or reference?

Comment: What version of C# are you using?

Comment: One workaround is to define separate generic extension methods with different `where` constraints.

Comment: @Dai, net 7.0 with C#11 (but I noticed this behavior with net 6.0 as well). Constraints do not allow overloads, extensions are for methods as you pointed out, I have to store the data.

Answer (score 1):

The `T?` meaning for reference types and value types is completely different. For value type it is really just a syntactic sugar for `Nullable<T>`, while for reference type it is merely an ignorable tip. If you want to have `MyClass` wrapping a nullable `int` then use it with `int?` type: `MyClass<int?>`.

You could constraint the `T` with `where T : struct` - then the `T?` will really mean `Nullable<T>` and you'll get `myField` equal to `null` initially when using `MyClass<int>`, but you will no longer be able to use e.g. `MyClass<string>`.

As far as I know you can't mix both behaviours and let the runtime choose one depending on the generic `T` type.